# prove that $\lim_{n\to∞} \frac{n!}{n^n}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, factorial

any sugestions?, by Stolz–Cesàro?.
The trouble says that first try with $k<n$ and then for a particular $k<\frac{n}{2}$ I try by definition of $\epsilon$ but it doesn't help

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing some logarithms or something? Or that the limit should be zero instead of one? As written this doesn't look true at all.

Comment: I think you will find it very hard to prove, since it is not true. That limit is $0$.

Comment: The above limit is $0$. This can be done in one short line, minimal machinery.  The expression is $\le \frac{1}{n}$.  The hint is kind of weird, too much work.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake, the limit goes to zero

Answer (score 8):

Every number in the product $n!$ is less than or equal to $n$. In particular, one of them is $1$. Can you use this to show $n! / n^n \leq 1/n$?

Answer (score 4):

There is a very simple approach: by the AM-GM inequality,
$$ n!^2 \leq \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{2n},$$
hence the wanted limit is clearly $\color{red}{0}$.

Answer (score 2):

$0\leq{n!}\leq{n^{n-1}}\implies$

$\frac{0}{n^n}\leq\frac{n!}{n^n}\leq\frac{n^{n-1}}{n^n}\implies$

$0\leq\frac{n!}{n^n}\leq\frac{1}{n}\implies$

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}0\leq\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}\leq\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\implies$

$0\leq\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}\leq0\implies$

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}=0$

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Stirling's approximation: $n!\sim \left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$ as $n\to \infty$